# How to configure php code to execute in a particular machine

Tags: php, web-services, networking

I want to run my PHP project on a particular server machine and set a license key option for it, so that it may not be copied or distributed to any machine. So i need to know the required procedure to solve this problem.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this. And actually more and more people finally realize that this is questionable in general. Such attempts cause all sorts of problems again and again, everyone gets frustrated. That is not how you should treat your customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two real and one group of self-lying solution in order to achieve "that it may not be copied or distributed".

Real solutions:

1) Write license and find layer. Organize business model so your customer will look for your valid-license-only services: updates and support.

2) Offer **code as a service** - do not give your app (source code) away.

Self deception "solution":

Go with code obfuscators/scramblers like Zend encoder, IonCube, bunch of freeware obfuscators available and so. **Besides making your product placement complicated with portability issues** (Zend Guard loader, IonCube loader and so), this will buy you **inability for non-programmers** to steal your code.

But remember: determined professional can deobfuscate/decode your code and noting can stop him eventually. If you gave code that works under some circumstances (i.e. before some date limit) it could work with limiting factor removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with wanting to protect your work and investment, but PHP is not the language to do this with, if you are going to share the code.

However, if your code allows this, you could run certain essential parts on your own server. The code that the client is allowed to run on their server must depend on it, so that without it that code doesn't perform certain essential functions. You should, of course, use a realiable server for this, and the functions you place on it should, preferably, not be time critical.

The code on your server could, for instance, be a SOAP API. Only users with a valid license can access it. In almost any application there's some functionality which you could hide in this way, but you have to plan this in advance. Adapting your project, after you've made it, can be difficult.

https://www.sitepoint.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1

**Note:** Since it is your software interacting with your server, you don't have to follow a standard like SOAP. So in this case it's just an example.